# Why 2 tables are showing when actually 1 table existed in the dataset in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a .xlsx file containing only 1 sheet. When I load it in PowerBI, it shows 2 tables of the same information. I tried to load the dataset with only 1 table but it fails. Why is that?

[Power BI load data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojfHS.png)

Comment: What is the error message or erratic behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the symbols next to the object names are different:

- *Table1* is a named table range with a header row (blue top row). You don't have to promote the header.
- *Customers* is a sheet that might contain multiple tables. If it's just one table PowerQuery will promote the header for you.

The preview window allows you to see what will be imported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-import-excel-workbooks